# Empty email python SMTP library

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp, smtplib

```py
def mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(env, password)
    server.sendmail(env,rec,msg =str(list))
    print("Login no servidor efetuado com Sucesso")
    print("Email enviado para " + rec)
    server.close()
```

I use this code to send an email but the email comes empty i tryed to swap msg = str(list) to just list tried remove message and type in the third argument just a string and emails always come empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
server.sendmail(env,rec,msg =str(list))
```

You see what your message contains?

```
str(list)
```

Try typing this same thing in a scope in which `list` is not overwritten (because `list` is not reassigned in your `mail` function).

```
>>> str(list)
"<class 'list'>"
```

For sure that's not the right way of doing this.

---

What's more, in the same line of code above I don't see the assignation of `env` and `rec`, so I guess there must be some error there.

Comment: The thing is i tryed to replace str(list) with a string like "Test" even took out msg and just left the "Text " string all empty its not about the list variable

Comment: So, could you edit the answer to include the whole code? Because you're calling a function with three arguments and the code you posted doesn't include the assignation for any of that variables. What's more **never** overwrite classes like list.